# Grand total is storing as 0 while ordering the products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, grand-total, subtotal, zero-subtotal

Before placing the order it shows correctly the order total but after placing the order, it stores the grand total as 0 in the database table. How to fix this problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: check your sales_order page both frontend and backend then let me know there also order total show as '0'

Comment: let me know that have you checked it there also  grand total reflects as '0'

Comment: Yeah in the backend also it reflects as 0 for the grand total.

Comment: have you check  the order information in frontend.  And you check the grandTotal shown in cart and checkout page

Comment: have you used any plugin or observer  like place order before or after

Comment: Clear the cache and run it again and run it in private window sometimes  cache also happen this things.

Comment: i check the checkout folder there is no problem. i don't know  whether if any other extension may get into the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a webkul wallet module. By default it will save grand total as 0 only.