# Magento2 : Grand total changes to zero after placing the order

Tags: magento2, error, sales-order, grand-total, conflict

I am facing the issue of grand total becoming zero after placing the order in magento2. Some 3rd party module changes that. I want to know how to recollect the grand total again and set it as while placing the order. So it can avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to disable that extension which causing an issue. Second thing for updating total for a placed order, you need to edit orders from the backend and save that order. So it will update cancel the current order and create a new one with same information.

I hope this will help you.

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Please check this. I clearly mentioned about the problem. I don't want to disable that. It is offline payment -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290817/grand-total-is-storing-as-0-while-ordering-the-products-in-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment417676_290817

Comment: Then you need to find out an issue from third party extension and fix that issue.

Comment: I am unable to fix that. All I am asking is how to set the grand total after placing the order through the events. Please give me some sample examples.